# How to combine ISBLANK AND if

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I am trying to pre-populate a column in SharePoint to show as 'live' where a separate column is either blank or has a date > than 'today' and to show as 'closed' where a date is entered and is < today.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below formula:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK([Date Field]),AND(NOT(ISBLANK([Date Field])),[Date Field]>TODAY())),"Live","Closed")
```

[image]

Here `[Date Field]` is the Date field so replace it with Display name of your Date Field.

Read more about Calculated column [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/examples-of-common-formulas-in-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3)

Answer (score 0):

Create a calculated column for your requirements. Use formula like below for your calculated column:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Due Date]),"live",IF([Due Date]>TODAY(),"live","closed"))
```

**OR**

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK([Due Date]),[Due Date]>TODAY()),"live",IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK([Due Date])),[Due Date]<TODAY()),"closed",""))
```

Use correct *display name* of your date column in place of **Due Date** in above formula.

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).

**Official Documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14))